# elastic / elasticsearch-ruby gem || How call put_lifecycle method

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch-ruby (7.15.0)

I want to create a lifecycle policy.

I'm doing it like this....

```rb
  $elastic ||= Elasticsearch::Client.new(
    host: $settings['business.elastic_server'],
    user: $settings['business.elastic_username'],
    password: $settings['business.elastic_password'],
    log: false
  )

 $elastic.ilm.put_lifecycle(
    policy: 'my_policy',
    body: {"policy":{"phases":{"delete":{"min_age":"30d","actions":{"delete":{}}}}}}
  )
```

Then I got.

```
elasticsearch-7.15.0/lib/elasticsearch.rb:43:in `method_missing': undefined method `ilm'
```

What is the proper way to call put_lifecycle method?

Thanks

Comment: Solved. https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby/issues/2137

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I decided to upgrade my Gemfile with gem 'elasticsearch', '8.6.0' and works perfect.

The explanation has been provided by Fernando Briano (picandocodigo ) as @vasily-kolesnikov said in a comment

*In version 7.15 of the client, the index lifecycle management APIs are available through the elasticsearch-xpack gem. Have you required it in your code? The rest of the code looks ok, it should work if you have required elasticsearch-xpack.
Let me know if that's the issue, thanks!*

*The best option is to use the client minor version equal to the server's minor version.*